# Buttons not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, button, text

I have a very simple window near a red ball in the tray (see following picture)

[image]

when I click on the Exit button (esci) I want to change the content of the two bottons while serializing

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  string strButtonName = (sender as Button).Name;

  switch (strButtonName.ToUpper())
  {
    case "BTEXIT":
      string strError;
      this.btShow.Content = "Serializing";
      this.btExit.Content = "Please wait";
      this.UpdateLayout();
      Serializers.Logger.WriteLog_Reflection<PCDmisLogEntry>;
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);<---simulates a long serialization process
      Environment.Exit(0);
      break;
  }
  this.Close();
}
```

but nothing happens.

Thanx

Comment: Do I need a thread to update a button?!

Comment: you don't need threading the change the button, but you can put that last part in thread to exit the app. When you're in the click event handler you are on the UI thread, so the painting won't occur until you are done with the handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to

```
case "BTEXIT":
      string strError;
      this.btShow.Content = "Serializing";
      this.btExit.Content = "Please wait";
      Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => { }), DispatcherPriority.Render);
      this.UpdateLayout();
      Serializers.Logger.WriteLog_Reflection<PCDmisLogEntry>;
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
      Environment.Exit(0);
      break;
```

Comment: Thanks, that is working fine. Would you please just elaborate a bit what was the problem? By doing so do you just force the update with a higher priority? Is this therefore a solution that can always be used when forcing an update is necessary?